# remove characters before "-" in a string - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am pulling a list of sales part from a table and need to remove the prefix of each part. I attempted to use REGEXP_REPLACE() but am not familiar with the correct syntax to use. What i would like to do is find the first "-" in the string and remove everything before it.

Example. CTC-5D6539

Want: 5D6539

```
SELECT sp.catalog_no AS "Sales Part", 
       sp.catalog_desc AS "Sales Part Description",
       ifsapp.sales_group_api.get_description(sp.catalog_group) AS "Mfg Id",
       sp.list_price AS "List Price",
       ifsapp.inventory_part_api.get_weight_net(sp.contract,sp.part_no) AS "Weight",
       ifsapp.hb_utility_api.get_sales_price(sp.contract,'102630',sp.catalog_no) AS "Net Price",
       avail AS "Qty Avail"
FROM sales_part sp LEFT JOIN available_qty av ON (sp.contract = av.contract) AND (sp.catalog_no = av.catalog_no)
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: If your on SQL server I'd use a combination of right, charindex and len.  Right(ColumnName,Len(ColumnName)-Charindex(ColumnName)-1).  You may need to use a case expression if there is not always a "-" in every string.

Comment: @Bee_Riii, `CharIndex` takes at least 2 parameters, 3rd is optional. `Charindex('-',ColumnName)`

Comment: the data is being pulled out of a Oracle database

Comment: Simple: `SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, '-')+1)`

Comment: @denoeth that did exactly what i needed. Thank you!

Comment: @WEI_DBA yes of course!  I've obviously been using redgate sql prompt too long.

Answer (score 2):

```
right(MyColumn, len(MyColumn) - charindex('-', MyColumn))
```

OR

```
right(MyColumn, len(MyColumn) - CASE WHEN MyColumn LIKE '%-%' THEN charindex('-', MyColumn) ELSE 0 END)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using a REGEXP_REPLACE() solution that you asked for:

```
SQL> with tbl(str) as (
     select 'CTC-5D6539' from dual
   )
   select regexp_replace(str, '^(.*?)-') part
   from tbl;

PART
------
5D6539
```

The regular expression matches zero or more characters from the start of the string to the first hyphen and replaces them with nothing (deletes them). It stops at the first hyphen so the part can contain hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartIndex int, @EndIndex int;
DECLARE @Str varchar(100);
SET @Str = 'This is a (sentence to use for a) test';

SELECT @StartIndex = CHARINDEX('(', @Str, 0), @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(')', @Str, 0);

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Str, 0, @StartIndex) + SUBSTRING(@Str, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Str) - @EndIndex) AS [Method1],
    LEFT(@Str, @StartIndex - 1) + RIGHT(@Str, LEN(@Str) - @EndIndex) AS [Method2];
```